# How to remove gaussian noise?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have to remove gaussian noise from this image (before, I had to filter it and add the noise). Then, I have to use function "o" and my grade is based on how low result of this function will be. I am trying and trying different things, but I can't remove this noise so I can get a good grade :/ any help please?

```
   img=imread('liftingbody.png');
   img=double(img)/255;
   maska1=[1 1 1; 1 5 1; 1 1 1]/13;
   odfiltrowany=imfilter(img,maska1);
   zaszumiony=imnoise(odfiltrowany,'gaussian');
   nowy=wiener2(zaszumiony);
   nowy4=medfilt2(nowy);

   o=1/512.*sqrt(sum(sum(img-nowy4).^2));

   subplot(311); imshow(img);
   subplot(312); imshow(zaszumiony);
   subplot(313); imshow(nowy);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try convoluting a Gaussian filter with your noisy image to remove Gaussian noise like below:

```
nowx=conv2(zaszumiony,fspecial('gaussian',[3 3],1.5),'same')/(sum(sum(fspecial('gaussian',[3 3],1.5))));
```

It should reduce your o function somewhat.

Try playing around with the strength of the filter (i.e. the 1.5 value) and the size of the kernel (i.e. [3 3] value) to reduce the noise to a minimum.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @ALM865's answer, you can also use `imfilter`.  In fact, this is the recommended function that you use for images as `imfilter` has optimizations in place specifically for images.  `conv2` is the more general function for any 2D signal.

I have also answered how to choose the standard deviation and ultimately the size of your a Gaussian filter / kernel here:  [By which measures should I set the size of my Gaussian filter in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23832852/by-which-measures-should-i-set-the-size-of-my-gaussian-filter-in-matlab/23833014#23833014)

In essence, once you choose which standard deviation you want, you find a `floor(6*sigma) + 1 x floor(6*sigma) + 1` Gaussian kernel to use in your filtering operation.  Assuming that `sigma = 2`, you would get a `13 x 13` kernel.  As ALM865 has said, you can create a Gaussian kernel using `fspecial`.  You specify the `'gaussian'` flag, followed by the size of the kernel and the standard deviation after.  As such:

```
sigma = 2;
width = 6*sigma + 1;
kernel = fspecial('gaussian', [width width], sigma);
out = imfilter(zaszumiony, kernel, 'replicate');
```

`imfilter` takes in the image you want to filter, the convolution kernel you want to use to filter the image, and an optional flag that specifies what happens along the image pixel borders when the kernel doesn't fit completely inside the image.  `'replicate'` means that it simply copies the pixels along the borders, thus **replicating** them.  There are other options, such as padding with a value (usually zero), circular padding and symmetric padding.

Play around with the standard deviation until you get what you believe is a good result.