# How to convert cv2.addWeighted and cv2.GaussianBlur into MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, opencv, image-processing

I have this Python code:

```
cv2.addWeighted(src1, 4, cv2.GaussianBlur(src1, (0, 0), 10), src2, -4, 128)
```

How can I convert it to Matlab? So far I got this:

```
f = imread0('X.jpg'); 
g = imfilter(f, fspecial('gaussian',[size(f,1),size(f,2)],10));
alpha = 4;
beta = -4;
f1 = f*alpha+g*beta+128;
```

I want to subtract local mean color image.

Input image:

[image]

Blending output from OpenCV:

[image]

Comment: `cv2.addWeighted()` does exactly what your code is doing in your post (without the Gaussian blur).  What exactly is your question?

Comment: OK, well the code is essentially the same, but you weren't blurring the image properly.  See my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation for [`cv2.addWeighted`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#addweighted) has the definition such that:

```
cv2.addWeighted(src1, alpha, src2, beta, gamma[, dst[, dtype]]) → dst
```

Also, the operations performed on the output image is such that:

[image]
<sub>(source: [opencv.org](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/_images/math/d9e87b75f6c0526dfca3f8c483fbda1ad7251046.png))</sub>

Therefore, what your code is doing is exactly correct... at least for `cv2.addWeighted`.  You take `alpha`, multiply this by the first image, then `beta`, multiply this by the second image, then add `gamma` on top of this.  The only intricacy left to deal with is `saturate`, which means that any values that are beyond the dynamic range of the data type you are dealing with, you cap it at that much.  Because there is a potential for negatives to occur in the result, the `saturate` option simply means to make any values that are negative `0` and any values that are greater than the maximum expected to that max.  In this case, you'll want to make any values larger than 1 equal to 1.  As such, it'll be a good idea to convert your image to `double` through [`im2double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/im2double.html) because you want to allow the addition and subtraction of values beyond the dynamic range to happen first, *then* you saturate after.  By using the default image precision of the image (which is `uint8`), the saturation will happen even before the `saturate` operation occurs, and that'll give you the wrong results.  Because you're doing this `double` conversion, you'll want to convert the addition of 128 for your `gamma` to 0.5 to compensate.

Now, the only slight problem is your Gaussian Blur.  [Looking at the documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#gaussianblur), by doing `cv2.GaussianBlur(src1, (0, 0), 10)`, you are telling OpenCV to infer on the mask size while the standard deviation is 10.  MATLAB does not infer the size of the mask for you, so you need to do this yourself.  A common practice is to simply find six-times the standard deviation, take the `floor` and add 1.  This is for both the horizontal and vertical dimensions of the mask.  You can see my post here on the justification as to why this is common practice:  [By which measures should I set the size of my Gaussian filter in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23832852/by-which-measures-should-i-set-the-size-of-my-gaussian-filter-in-matlab/23833014#23833014)

Therefore, in MATLAB, you would do this with your Gaussian blur instead. BTW, it's simply `imread`,  not `imread0`:

```
f = im2double(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/kl3Md.jpg')); %// Change - Reading image directly from StackOverflow
sigma = 10; %// Change
sz = 1 + floor(6*sigma); %// Change
g = imfilter(f, fspecial('gaussian', sz, sigma)); %// Change

%// Rest of the code is the same
alpha = 4;
beta = -4;
f1 = f*alpha+g*beta+0.5; %// Change

%// Saturate
f1(f1 > 1) = 1;
f1(f1 < 0) = 0;
```

I get this image:

[image]

Take a note that there is a slight difference in the way this appears between OpenCV in MATLAB... especially the hallowing around the eye.  This is because OpenCV does something different when inferring the mask size for the Gaussian blur.  This I'm not sure what is going on, but how I specified the mask size by looking at the standard deviation is one of the most common heuristics for it.  Play around with the standard deviation until you get something you like.

Comment: thanks for blurring concepts, but the blending image output is same as my previous output.

Comment: Not for me. Please upload an example image so I can try it. I ran this on a few of my own images. The outputs are different.

Comment: i have upload input image and output image which is generated from openvc

Comment: @HEMANTKUMAR Have a look.  I had to do some extra things.

Comment: i obtained desired output without saturation

Comment: why need u convert uint8 image into doble ?

Comment: I explain it in my answer. Read it again.