# Plot point density

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to plot the point density for a large set of points (see image). How would you do it? I tried using the code below, but I got the error `Error using griddedInterpolant
The grid vectors are not strictly monotonic increasing` (I guess because the points are not ordered).

[image]

```
%# bin centers (integers)
xbins = floor(min(X)):step_for_plot:ceil(max(X));
ybins = floor(min(Y)):step_for_plot:ceil(max(Y));
xNumBins = numel(xbins); 
yNumBins = numel(ybins);

%# map X/Y values to bin indices
Xi = round( interp1(xbins, 1:xNumBins, X, 'linear', 'extrap') );
Yi = round( interp1(ybins, 1:yNumBins, Y, 'linear', 'extrap') );

%# limit indices to the range [1,numBins]
Xi = max( min(Xi,xNumBins), 1);
Yi = max( min(Yi,yNumBins), 1);

%# plot 2D histogram
imagesc(xbins, ybins, Data), axis on %# axis image
colormap hot; colorbar
hold on, plot(X, Y, 'b.', 'MarkerSize',1), hold off
```

Comment: I dont know what you are triying to do exactly, but in your code there is written "plot 2D histogram". What about hist() and histogram() functions?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is show (for example on a colormap) the density of points per pixel.

Comment: Do you just want to count the number of points per bin (i.e. per pixel) or are you interested in the density of the neighboring pixels as well?

Comment: Also can you provide some simple sample input data?

Comment: @Dan: I just want to plot the number of points per bin. I uploaded a dataset here: http://cl.ly/text/3e0y2m2P3q0o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem using [`hist3`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/stats/hist3.html). Here is the code I used:

```
n = hist3(Data,[100,100]); 
n1 = n';
n1(size(n,1) + 1, size(n,2) + 1) = 0;

xb = linspace(min(Data(:,1)),max(Data(:,1)),size(n,1)+1);
yb = linspace(min(Data(:,2)),max(Data(:,2)),size(n,1)+1);

g = figure();
h = pcolor(xb,yb,n1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the points per bin then why are you interpolating?

```
hgram = accumarray([Y(:), X(:)], 1, [yNumBins xNumBins])
```

otherwise perhaps an alternative for that could be to think of it as an image and blur the image. So taking `hgram` from above:

```
heatmap = conv2(hgram, kernel, 'same');
imshow(heatmap/max(heatmap(:)))
```

where `kernel` could be very simple like:

```
ones(n)
```

or more sophisticated like a [gaussian filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13193248/how-to-make-a-gaussian-filter-in-matlab)

Comment: `hgram` was from a previous test, and that's why it's there. I just need to plot the density of points from the `Data` matrix

Comment: @albus_c 2 points, (1) `hgram` wasn't in your code...? and (2) you need to define what you mean by point density. This code adjusts each pixel according to the number of points in it's neighbours, that sounds like a measure of point density to me. Have you tried it on your data?

Comment: OK things were easier than expected. I solved the problem using hist3 (http://www.mathworks.se/help/stats/hist3.html).

Comment: @albus_c then you should add the code as an answer to your own question